# Querying JSON (specific situation)

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am trying to query a specific example of JSON, see below:

[image]

The column name is "values". If I use `values -> 'members'` I will get everything underneath. However, if I want the "gender" using `values -> 'members' ->> 'gender'` - nothing returns.

I believe this is because there is a "+" underneath members, so there is a field after "members" and before "gender" that I need to write in the query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining your members as an array.  Therefore (if you are using PostgreSQL), the correct query is:

```
postgres=# select (values->'members')->0->>'gender' from my_table;
 ?column? 
----------
 male
(1 row)
```

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue and worked perfectly (using PostgreSQL)